# passing 'addEventListener' name as a parameter

Tags: javascript

To simplify, I want to add an event that say *hello* to a button :

```js
var b= document.getElementById("palabras");
function fun2(){
 alert("hello");
}
function e(func){
 b.window[func]("click", fun2);
}
e("addEventListener");
```

```html
<button id="palabras">words</button>
```

The result in console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`

Comment: It's not a method of window, but of the element. You also don't do `d.window.addEventListener` do you?

Answer (score 1):

The event listener needs to be added to the element, not to `b['window']`.

Change

```
b.window[func]("click", fun2);
```

to

```
b[func]("click", fun2);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var b= document.getElementById("palabras");
function fun2(){
 alert("hello");
}
function e(func){
 b[func]("click", fun2);
}
e("addEventListener");
```

```html
<button id="palabras">words</button>
```

Comment: Running `window[func]===addEventListener` on console gives me `true` being `func = "addEventListener"` then why is wrong?. Another question would be why `b.[func]` is wrong as well, with the dot ?

Comment: @user2495207 Here, `func` is `addEventListener`, and you're basically doing `window.addEventListener===addEventListener`. This function works on any [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), and `window` happens to be the default one. For example, doing `window.setTimeout()` is exactly the same this as doing `setTimeout()` (unless you declare a function with the same name). About your second question: `b[func]` is called bracket notation, and allows you to use a variable name for your function. `b.func`, however, expects the function named `func` to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `window`, check the working code -

```
<script>
var b= window.document.getElementById("palabras");
console.log(b);
function fun2(){
    alert("hello");
}
function e(func){
    b[func]("click", fun2);
}
e("addEventListener");
</script>
```

If you console `document.getElementById("palabras");` it will console the target and on that target you need to `addEventListner` so no need for `window` here, just use `b[func]("click", fun2);`.